# replace missing values in julia DataFrame only for subset of columns

Tags: dataframe, julia, dataframes.jl

New to Julia alert! I have the following Julia DataFrame that includes missing values:

```
dat = DataFrame(a = [1,missing,3], b = [missing,5,6], c = [7,8,missing])
```

I want to replace missing values only for the following subset of the columns

```
relevant_cols = [:a, :b]
```

and leave the other column (c) the way it is.

The following options replace the missing values in the relevant columns, but they both drop the other column c which I want to keep just the way it is.

```
 coalesce.(dat[!,relevant_cols], 0)
 mapcols(col -> replace(col, missing => 0), dat[!,relevant_cols])
```

How can I replace missing values in a subset of columns but still keep the others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ifelse` might be the most straightforward way

```
cols = [:a, :b]

dat[:, cols] = ifelse.(ismissing.(dat[:, cols]), 0, dat[:, cols]);

dat
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b       c
     │ Int64?  Int64?  Int64?
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │      1       0        7
   2 │      0       5        8
   3 │      3       6  missing
```

or using a loop and `replace`

```
cols = [:a, :b]

for i in cols
  dat[:, i] = replace(dat[:, i], missing => 0)
end

dat
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a       b       c
     │ Int64?  Int64?  Int64?
─────┼─────────────────────────
   1 │      1       0        7
   2 │      0       5        8
   3 │      3       6  missing
```

Answer (score 1):

or

```
julia> transform!(dat, relevant_cols .=> ByRow(x -> coalesce(x, 0)), renamecols=false)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a      b      c
     │ Int64  Int64  Int64?
─────┼───────────────────────
   1 │     1      0        7
   2 │     0      5        8
   3 │     3      6  missing
```